# How to get rid of blank pages in my SSRS report

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

My spec says 1 inch margins A4 size (i.e. width is 8.27in).

I have a matrix positioned in top left corner, one level of parent grouping with **page break**, text data is in one cell in the parent grouping column (width=6.27in), detail column next to it is set to hidden (I don't need it, cannot delete it). Parent grouping is required only because I am reusing an existing stored procedure used in another report but for this report I only need relevant distinct rows.

When I run the report for particular set of parameters in preview mode I get 3 pages however when I switch to Print Layout view in Visual Studio I get 7 pages alternating blank pages. So my question is how do I get rid of the blank pages?

**6.27in of the first column cannot be compromised**. The text has a hyphenated text in it that splits on the hyphen if it matters.

I can set the right margin to any width and my dummy detail column (thus resize the body to accommodate - I can assure you the combined width can be set so it is less than 8.27in) to any width and it makes no difference still get a blank page every second page, i.e. per parent grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after a hours of stuffing around I found 2 solutions but the second solution I went with!

Option 1: was able to delete the default Details Grouping and leave the Parent Group in tact and it works - yeh no blank pages!

Option 2: was to delete the parent grouping but add my grouping on the Detail group and that also worked like a charm, and this solution was better as I then able to create extra tablix rows.

Simple as that.